# Как убрать кнопку ReplyKeyboard после нажатия на неё?

Tags: python, telebot

Вот код

```py
def proverka_btc(message, input_data, output_data, btc_price):
    wallet = message.text
    button = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    button.add(KeyboardButton("Подтверждаю Оплату"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"*Вы обмениваете {input_data} BTC на {output_data} RUB*.\n\n" f'Ваш счёт: {wallet}\n\n' f"❗️*Ожидаем оплаты в размере {output_data} RUB по реквизитам:* `bc1qf3tavj25mv6k3rdn8ludqlcpv6efq2xjegh4mm`", parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=button)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, finish, input_data=input_data, output_data=output_data, btc_price=btc_price, wallet=wallet)
```

При вводе такого метода `reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()` выдает ошибку из-за слова `types`, а метод `one_time_keyboard=True` не помог.

Comment: У `ReplyKeyboardRemove` нет аргумента `one_time_keyboard`. Если пишите про ошибку, то показывайте ошибку и код

Comment: Конструктор ReplyKeyboardRemove: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/68c1fe8cb5b5fc2f2e4ba2781e19b07f84158a72/telebot/types.py#L2026 . Конструктор ReplyKeyboardMarkup: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/68c1fe8cb5b5fc2f2e4ba2781e19b07f84158a72/telebot/types.py#L2116

Answer (score 0):

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"текст", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```